# How to efficiently identify "similar-HSV-to-neightbours" pixels in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, imagefilter

My image (`np.array` with shape `[Y] [X] [RGB]` contains glyph-graphics, which form regions of similar-HSL pixels. e.g. (magnified):

[image]

I'm trying to identify the HSL value of the text.

Throwing all pixels into scikit's `kmeans` *might* do the trick, as it will return clusters.

However I need efficiency. If I could first restrict the pixels-set to "those with 8 similar-HSL neighbours", this would boost performance significantly.

Something like:

```py
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(S, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
hues = hsv[:,:,0]

THRESH = 3
isclose = lambda hues_matrix_A, hues_matrix_B): \
    np.abs(hues_matrix_B - hues_matrix_A) < THRESH
mask = 
    is_close(hues, np.roll(hues,-1, axis=0)) & 
    is_close(hues, np.roll(hues,+1, axis=0)) & 
    is_close(hues, np.roll(hues,-1, axis=1)) & 
    is_close(hues, np.roll(hues,+1, axis=1))
```

That does the up/down/left/right neighbours and it is already ugly. Ideally I would test against the diagonal neighbours also, but that would involve a 2-axis-`roll`:

```
top_left_neighbour = np.roll(np.roll(hues,-1, axis=1),-1, axis=0)
```

eek. Does there exist a tool for this job? Interface might look like this:

```
mask = proximity_mask(src=hues_matrix, kernel=np.ones((3,3)), proximity=3)
```

And if not, what would be an intelligent construction?

Comment: Sounds like a convolution (filter2d in opencv)...

Answer (score 0):

From numpy 1.20+ you have [sliding_window_view](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
# size will be 1-pixel less on each side
hue_nbhds = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
    hue, (3,3)
)

# reshape to 3D
hue_nbhds = hue_nbhds.reshape(*hue_nbhds.shape[:2], -1)

# 
mask = (np.abs(hue_nbhds - hue[1:-1,1:-1, None]) < 3).all(-1)
```

But then you don't really get much from the mask:

[image]